# Can I use Scala options to avoid the following NoSuchElementException?

Tags: scala

I have the following HashMap

```
val lastAsk = new HashMap[String, Quote]
```

Quote objects have a price() method

The following

```
lastAsk(lastSecurity).price
```

throws NoSuchElementException if lastSecurity is not a key. To fix I could use contains to check then return -1 if the key is not found.  However this feels like a hack can I use Option here to engineer a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html) has method `get` that returns `Option`, so you can write something like this:

```
lastAsk get lastSecurity map (_ price) getOrElse 0
```

You can either use option further in your code or provide some default with the help of option's method `getOrElse` (in my example it's `0`).

Comment: Another +1 for avoiding the `;`